# How to pass jQuery Array into Spring using Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring

Here's my jQuery Array - ansList

```
$("#saveAndSubmitButton").click(function(){
    var ansList=[];
    var i=0;
    for(i=0;i<queListSize;i++){
        if($("#value1"+i).is(':checked')){
            ansList.push("yes");
        }
        else if($("#value2"+i).is(':checked')){
            ansList.push("no");
        }
    }       
    goToSaveAndSubmitAction(ansList);
    }
});

function goToSaveAndSubmitAction(answersList){

var inputForSaveAndSubmit={
    ansList:answersList 
};
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"../../restful/workflow/saveAndSubmitAction",
    data:inputForSaveAndSubmit,
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(jsonData){
        if(jsonData.success){
           alert('Inside Success');

        }


    },
    error:function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          // showAlertMessage("error",textStatus);
    }
});
}
```

In Spring my method signature is

```
@RequestMapping(value="/workflow/saveAndSubmitAction")
public @ResponseBody String  saveAndSubmitAction(@RequestParam(value="ansList",
    required=false) String[] ansList ){
}
```

When i'm debugging this code to see if any value is getting populated in ansList, i'm getting null for ansList...

What could be the problem??

Answer (score 0):

You just need let jQuery use the traditional encoding method.

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"../../restful/workflow/saveAndSubmitAction",
    data:$.param(inputForSaveAndSubmit, true),    ,
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(jsonData){
       if(jsonData.success){
          alert('Inside Success');
       }
   },
   error:function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      // showAlertMessage("error",textStatus);
   }
});
```

or call this before you submit an XHR

```
jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
```